# Application cannot connect to HAProxy Database

Tags: haproxy, database

I am trying to connect my [GLPI](https://glpi-project.org/) project to my HAProxy DB Server, I followed [this guide](https://linoxide.com/cluster/mariadb-centos-7-galera-cluster-haproxy/) to set it up. I am using CentOS 8 with Nginx and here's my HAProxy config:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local2
        maxconn 1024
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin     
defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn 1024
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms

listen mariadb_cluster
## MariaDB balance leastconn - the cluster listening on port 3030.
        bind 0.0.0.0:3030
        mode tcp
        balance leastconn
        option httpchk
        server node1 192.168.30.14:3306 check port 9200
        server node2 192.168.30.15:3306 check port 9200
        server node3 192.168.30.16:3306 check port 9200 backup

listen stats
## HAProxy stats web gui running on port 9000 - username and password: howtoforge.
        bind 0.0.0.0:9000
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /stats
        stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics
        stats auth haproxyadmin:adminpass
        stats admin if TRUE
```

My stats page:
[Haproxy Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H49a7.png)

And my GLPI config file

```
<?php
class DB extends DBmysql {
   public $dbhost     = '192.168.30.11:3030';
   public $dbuser     = 'glpi';
   public $dbpassword = 'glpipass';
   public $dbdefault  = 'glpi';
}
```

I can connect to my HAProxy server just fine by using:

> mysql -u glpi -p -h 192.168.30.11 --port 3030

Usually I get SELinux messages that can be solved with `semanage` but that is not the case this time around.

Comment: Check the implementation of your PHP class. Both `PDO` and `mysqli_*` use a separate parameter for the port, not the `host:port` format. Most probably you need to set a separate variable for the port.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I just checked the [source code of GLPI](https://github.com/glpi-project/glpi/blob/e914b1d0eebaa4f4391bfe6d238c74ce6c4b45f2/inc/dbmysql.class.php), it handles the host:port format correctly.

Comment: Actual error messages you encounter when you try to connect to your server would be helpful.

Comment: Actually I check every log possible, messages, error logs, haproxy logs, and I found nothing. Not even anything related to mysql for the past couple minutes. I have SELinux disabled on my DB Clusters plus all necessary ports are open. Is there any way to configure haproxy to log every connection attempt?

Comment: Your PHP script should report an error when it fails to connect. If not you may have to increase the log verbosity.

Comment: The only PHP messages are about a missing CSS file? My collague just told me that they might have disabled outgoing connections from the server. I'll look into it.

Comment: No, it's not the servers fault, does it matter if I was testing using OracleVM? Or somethings just notright with my configuration, I tried removing the 9200 checks, did the setsebool for haproxy, still, no luck. I'll read later on how to improve my logs so I can provide something useful...